# Servlet filter applied twice

Tags: spring-boot, filtering

I have an spring boot application exposing rest endpoints, inside the project there is a library that applies a filter:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {}
```

It works fine, but there is a weird behavior I found. whenever my library(the one with the filter) makes a remote call to another rest service(i do it to evaluate certain logic based on the response), when that service returns a response, before returning, the filter is applied again, and of course, I do not want this behavior.

I am 100% certain this is what causes the 2nd call to the filter because if I omit the rest call, the filter is applied only once.

Comment: Are you calling a service in your own application? Then ofcourse it will call the filter as it is just a new request.

Comment: any idea how can i create a rule to ignore internal requests?

Comment: It is not an internal request it is just a regular request like anything else. Why do you even do a rest call instead of making a direct call to the java backed service?

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing "internal rest requests" ? instead of calling directly the underlying service?

Comment: What do you mean by calling directly? I am invoking the service using a rest call, isn't that a direct call?

In case you mean something like a library invocation, well, my applications live in the cloud, so, they communicate through rest

Comment: declaring filter like that will be used for all paths, you can target un specific path by using FilterRegistrationBean

Answer (score 0):

use a FilterRegistrationBean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> loggingFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> registrationBean 
      = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
         
    registrationBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/users/*");
         
    return registrationBean;    
}
```